# How to marshal paragraph data (org.docx4j.wml.PPr class) and unmarshal it back again?

Tags: java, serialization, jaxb, marshalling, docx4j

I am following @JasonPlutext's approach to edit word document on browser from here [docx-html-editor](https://github.com/plutext/docx-html-editor).
The code here maintains http session and saves design and formatting information in session cookie throughout the entire roadtrip (docx-html-docx) process.

My requirement is I don't want to depend on http session and want to save paragraph design information in local storage.

I tried following ways to achieve it:

1. serializing instance of WordProcessingMLPackage and retrieve it later, but as this class is very huge bucket of information of various types, I couldn't find any way to serialize it.
2. I tried to marshal only required user data (Ex. {"DOCX4J_EDITOR:p75": <-instance of PPr->}). I used javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext and javax.xml.bind.Marshaller for it but it gives the following error: `There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml}dataBinding.`

My question is what is best way to save design information of paragraphs and retrieve them later.

Comment: Seems like you have a dataBinding element in your PPr, or the object you think is a PPr is actually a dataBinding?  This is an error, which is probably why you get that.  What is your marshalling code?  You can try for example XmlUtils.marshaltoString(ppr)

Comment: Thank you @JasonPlutext Sir. XmlUtils.marshaltoString(ppr) was exactly what I was looking for.